# How can you open files and print it in function using Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.6

I'm a student studying Python for the first 3 months. I want to create a function "def read_word_list(filename)" that open a file, return a list of words from the file.

I tried to name the action but when I test the function I got the error that the name is not defined even though I defined it many times.

Comment: Show your code, and the exact error/traceback!

Comment: Can you please show what you've tried? Can you provide an [mcve]? Post your expected output, and post the actually output/exception you're getting. Otherwise, I'm afraid this question is much to broad.

Comment: please post the code you have done !

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I hope that this will help you

```
def read_word_list(filename):
    fOpen = open(filename, 'r')
    lines = file1.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        print(line)
read_word_list("filename.txt")
```